# recursive calculation in sql view error GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate functions are not allowed in the recursive part

Tags: sql-server, recursion

I have a very simple SQL Server table and I want to find cost of each recipe. Each Recipe has a list of ingredients. A recipe may also have a sub recipes.

Simplest Example of RecipeId-1 Chicken sandwich which has below ingredients:

1. IngredientId-1 Bread (an ingredient) - Cost $1
2. IngredientId-2 Fried Chicken (an ingredient) - Cost $5
3. RecipeId-2 Garlic Sauce (a sub recipe) - Cost $2

Since garlic sauce RecipeId-2 is also a recipe (used as sub recipe above), it has below ingredients:

1. IngredientId-3 Raw Garlic - Cost $1.5
2. IngredientId-4 Water - Cost $0.5

Finally my table structure:

[image]

Now I want a view that gives me the cost of Chicken Sandwich, Something like 
Select * From RecursiveRecipeView Where RecipeId=1 and result will be: $8 (1+5+1.5+.5).

I have tried below query but I get error "GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate functions are not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'Tree'"

```
WITH Tree (RecipeId, Depth, SubRecipeId, Cost) AS (
SELECT RecipeId, 0 AS Depth, RecipeId AS SubRecipeId, SUM(Cost) AS [Cost] FROM RecipeIngredients
GROUP BY RecipeId
UNION ALL
SELECT RI.RecipeId, Parent.Depth + 1 AS Depth,
CONVERT(varchar(255), Parent.SubRecipeId) AS SubRecipeId, Parent.Cost + cast(sum(RI.cost) as float) AS [Cost] 
FROM RecipeIngredients RI
INNER JOIN Tree as Parent ON Parent.RecipeId = RI.SubRecipeId )SELECT distinct RecipeId, Depth, SubrecipeId, Cost FROM Tree
```

Please note that some recipes go even 10 levels deep. Can somebody help me on this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you've got some problems with your CTE.  It will recurse infinitely, which is not good.  I flipped your join between your `TREE` and `PARENT` objects.

Secondly, as has been pointed out, you need to pull the aggregation out of your CTE.  Just let your CTE select your details, and then sum it up in your final query.  One catch here is that you'll need to specify a particular RecipeID in the top level of your CTE, so that you actually have a "top" level.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/762cb/1)  (I added a third level and a just to test it).

```
WITH Tree (RecipeId, Depth, SubRecipeId, Cost) AS (
SELECT RecipeId, 
  0 AS Depth, 
  SubRecipeId, 
  Cost 
FROM RecipeIngredients 
  where recipeid = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  parent.RecipeId, 
  Parent.Depth + 1 AS Depth,
  ri.SubRecipeId AS SubRecipeId, 
  RI.cost as cost
FROM RecipeIngredients  RI
INNER JOIN Tree as Parent 
  ON Parent.subrecipeid = RI.recipeid 
)

SELECT * FROM Tree
--select sum(cost) from Tree
```

Comment: thanks i will check this. btw why did you put where recipeid=1. if you put where recipeid=1, i will never be able to find cost of recipeid 2

Comment: why did you put where recipeid=1. if you put where recipeid=1, i will never be able to find cost of recipeid 2

Comment: The `where recipe=1` clause is to ensure you only get one actual level in the top of your CTE.  Otherwise, you'll get every row in your table with a depth of 0, and then you'll start working through the children.